# javascript: clean way to have a return statement span multiple lines

Tags: javascript, return, multiline, line-continuation

i'd like to have a javascript return keyword on one line, and the thing it actually returns on the next line.
in python this would be something like

```
return \
    someValue
```

however due to the optionality of statement-terminating semicolons and the absence of a line-continuation character in javascript, the only approach i've come up with is the hackish

```
return false ||
    someValue;
```

motivation:
my actual code is like this. during development i sometimes comment out the second line to switch between GlobalScope.doSomething() and myThing.doSomething().  Admittedly this is a minor issue.

```
return false ||
    myThing.
    doSomething()
    .then(...)
    .then(...)
    .
```

Comment: I prefer parentheses: `return ( <newline> someValue <newline> );`

Comment: indeed. that's better for a simple case!   but in my actual actual code, the doSomething() is a promise chain which goes on for 10 or 15 lines and i'd prefer not to have a somewhat spurious close-parens at the end of them.

Comment: i would move the or below the return statement. the operands have the same column.

Comment: If it's a number you can use `return + <newline> someValue;`

Comment: A common idiom is `return myThing <newline>.doSomething() <newline>.then() <newline>.then() <newline>.then()` i.e. the `return myThing` on one line acts as an anchor for the rest of the fluent chain. Also, "*I'd prefer not to have a somewhat spurious close-parens*" Yeah, I agree, JS is full of trailing syntax like that IMHO. You kind of just get used to it at some point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual approach is to put the object from which you are chaining in the same line as the `return`:

```
return myThing
    .doSomething()
    .then(...)
    .then(...);
```

or

```
return myThing
.doSomething()
.then(...)
.then(...);
```

but you can also use parenthesis if you insist on separate lines and extra indentation:

```
return (
    myThing
    .doSomething()
    .then(...)
    .then(...)
);
```

Comment: thanks Bergi. i'm looking for something where i can comment/uncomment exactly one entire line to change the functionality in the way i want. your third suggestion achieves that, but it introduces a trailing close-paren. for now i'm sticking with the `false ||` thing.

Comment: @orionelenzil You can just swap two `return myThing` and `return otherThing` lines with comments?

Comment: :) yes, i could.